# File transfer over a serial line

Tags: linux, file-transfer, serial-port

I have 2 linux computers, and a serial line between them, one of them is only accessible through a serial line that has shell on it. How can I transfer files between the 2 computers?

I've heard that it can be done with some rz/sz magic...

Can I do the same trick with a pseudo-terminal instead of other computer?

Comment: Check out `Kermit` (not the frog) at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_%28protocol%29

Answer (score 4):

You need a terminal application like minicom. Then you connect the two computers, start minicom on one side, connect to the other side (the one where you can login) and use the [sz](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sz) command to send the file. Minicom will automatically detect the file transfer. Note that you might need to install the `sz` command on the login machine, how that is done is dependent on your distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Copying [txwikinger's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316/4499) answer, I would use [kermit](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ckututor.html), the grandfather of file transfer programs. We used it in the 80's, long before there was Linux. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_%28protocol%29) suggests it may be better than zmodem (sz).

An alternative approach is to use SLIP or PPP, as suggested by Axel. But this [howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO) for PPP is about 15 years old.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into the same issue and all I had was a prompt, but no network modules loaded, no rz/sz binaries, nor anything else in the target system I could make use of in order to transfer files.

But I had `echo` and I found a solution where everything needed was - yes - `echo`.

I came across **serio**, a very simple, clever and open source Python script (available here: https://github.com/devttys0/serio). All this tiny gem does is to echo every single byte from the source file onto the target's shell using `echo` and redirecting the output to a destination file.

So, first I needed to provide a shell on target (I did it using `minicom`), then leave `minicom` and issue something like this from the host machine:

```
./serio.py \
-s /path/to/input/file/in/host.bin \
-d /path/to/destination/on/target.bin \
-p /dev/ttyUSB0
```

As stated [in the project's page](https://github.com/devttys0/serio#readme):

> The only requirements on the embedded system is that it provides an
> interactive shell on the serial port, and that the shell's echo
> command supports the -n and -e options.

The transfer is, of course, very slow, but it will hopefully solve my issue.

Credits: I found this solution [here](http://andylinuxblog.blogspot.com/2014/11/serio-serial-file-transfer-program.html). It points to another repository (this one: https://code.google.com/archive/p/serio/source/default/source), while I got the code from github directly and it differs slightly from the one published in that blog. Choose the one which suits best your needs. :)

Comment: The serio.py linked here is still Python 2 but somebody ported it to Python 3: https://github.com/matteomartelli/serio/tree/python3 And that basically works, however, one shouldn't expect to transfer larger files before the heat death of the universe... i.e., it's quite slow.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the "Serial Line Internet Protocol" as described [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol).

Once two systems are interconnected by a slip line, you can use any IP-based tool (ftp, rcp, scp, ssh, ...) to exchange files. It probably takes too long to configure for a once-only purpose but might be worth looking at for embedded systems with RS232 port or old systems from a pre-LAN aera.

Comment: The link no longer exists.

Comment: Thank you. The link should work now for another 10 years.

Answer (score 1):

My way of transferring a file.bin via serial connection is to use openSSL tool since I don't have other options to do base64 encoding and back:

```
openssl enc -base64 <file.bin > file.b64
```

Decode:

```
openssl enc -base64 -d <file.b64 > file.bin
```

Answer (score 1):

first, you need a connection between host and the target.

for this example I use 2 pl2303 (connect both rx to tx and ground to ground) to connect 2 computers (host, target), this create a /dev/ttyUSB0 on both sides. Having busybox on target is possible to estabilish a connection between both.

on target you need a tty connection, you can have this on initrc or if you have a console, you can use getty directly to open an connection like this:
`# sh -c 'getty -Lin -l /bin/sh 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0' &`

on host you need putty to connect to target, like this:
`$ putty -serial -sercfg 115200,8,n,1 /dev/ttyUSB0`

to start receiving a file on target you run rx like this on putty connection:
`# rx file.bz2`

to start sending file on host you run sx like this:
`$ sx file.bz2 < /dev/ttyUSB0 > /dev/ttyUSB0`

you will see the blocks transfering, take a coffee and wait, remember this is a 115200 bauds, what its ~11 kb/s